# android two line listview row alignment

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I've a two line listview with the following XML for the row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/designation"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="2" 
    android:id="@+id/orderedValue"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    />  

</LinearLayout>
```

what I want is to have the first row (designation) to be at the exact vertical center of the row, and the second row (orderedValue) just below it

I've been trying with several combinations of LinearLayout/Relative layout, gravity vs layout_gravity for the TextViews to no avail

Any help/pointers here?

Comment: I couldn't understand how you want it. Could you illustrate by drawing?

Comment: iturki, here: bit.ly/OyDaql is a screenshot of hot it looks now. What I want is the first line to be in the middle of the row instead of it being at 1/3 from the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iTurki, thanks for the input, but I just solved it before reading your solution.

I switched to a relative layout and changed some parameters, most importantly adding: android:layout_centerVertical="true".

here is my final layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:padding="6dip"
  >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/designation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/orderedValue"       
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/designation"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textColor="#33B5E5"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    />  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you both for your interest!

Answer (score 1):

I'd make a blank `View` above the first `TextView` which can share the same weight as the text below it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip"
>

  <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />  

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/designation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:id="@+id/orderedValue"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    />  

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: nope, not working, I'm getting the same text distribution, first line @ 1/3 from top, second line @ 2/3 from top

Comment: If you remove the `android:gravity` tags does it produce the desired results?

Comment: I've made a change to the post--give that a try; if it doesn't work either, can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: no change eric (btw, appreciate your interest). screenshot here: http://bit.ly/OyDaql (layout is no yet fully styled though)

Comment: I'm not sure what to suggest. When I implement that, I get [this](http://imgur.com/GY7bV) (using a full layout, not a list). Something you could try is setting the `LinearLayout`'s height to `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'll try to put `designation` TextView inside a LinearLayout and use `android:layout_gravity` to center it. I tried this in my activity and it centered the first TextView. However, I'm not sure if it will work in your list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip"
android:gravity="center_vertical" >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/designation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="designation" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="2" 
    android:id="@+id/orderedValue"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:text="orderedValue" />  
</LinearLayout>
```